# Recorrer un string y cambiarlo

Tags: java, string

Quiero que dado un String de tipo "AbaBc" me devuleva "c" ya que si esta repetido por parejas la misma letra (da igual si es en mayúscula o en minúsculas) te la elimine de tu String.
De momento he desarrollarlo parte del código pero no se como completarlo. Gracias

```
    public static String processPolymer(String polymer) {
        String newPolymer = polymer.toLowerCase();
        
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newPolymer.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<newPolymer.length(); i++) {
                if (newPolymer.charAt(i)==newPolymer.charAt(j)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 0){
                
            }
        }return newPolymer;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print(processPolymer("abbAc"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la lógica que has puesto en tu pregunta, he creado un código para resolver el problema.

He trabajado en todo el código con el parámetro que recibe el método.

```java
    public static String processPolymer(String polymer) {
        String newPolymer = ""; // esto almacenará los que no tienen más de 1 aparición
        int contador = 0; // contaremos las apariciones con esta variable
        // esto está tal cual como lo planteas en tu pregunta, solo uso la variable que
        // es pasada como parámetro
        for(int i = 0; i < polymer.length(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < polymer.length(); j++){
                if(polymer.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == polymer.toLowerCase().charAt(j)){
                    contador++;
                }
            }
           //compruebo que las apariciones del char de turno sea uno
            if(contador == 1){
                //de ser así añadimos el char a nuestra variable que retornará el método
                newPolymer.append(polymer.toLowerCase().charAt(i));
            }
            contador = 0; // seteamos el contador para que vuelva a 0 en cada iteración
        }      
        return newPolymer; //retornamos
    }
```

- Yo dejé en esta línea  `newPolymer.append(polymer.toLowerCase().charAt(i));` que se encuentra dentro del `if` el método `toLowerCase()` de esta manera retorna todos las letras que tienen una aparición en minúsculas, pero se puede prescindir de este y retornará las letras como se pasaron como parámetro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hacer newPolymer +=  polymer.toLowerCase().charAt(i);  en un bucle es MUY MALA idea porque es muy ineficiente en Java mejor usar un StringBuilder y cambiarlo a : newPolymer.append(polymer.toLowerCase().charAt(i))

Comment: +1 tienes toda la razón!, no se si quieres que cambie esa parte de la respuesta y añado tu nombre como fuente :)

Comment: Sugiero que lo cambies para evitar performace O(n^2) en la concatenación. Es más correcto así.

Answer (score 0):

considera utilizar el siguiente algoritmo.

Saludos.

```
public static String processPolymer(String polymer) {
    String newPolymer = polymer.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < newPolymer.length(); i++) {
        if (repeatedEveryTime(newPolymer, newPolymer.charAt(i), 2)) {
            newPolymer = newPolymer.replace(Character.toString(newPolymer.charAt(i)), "");
        }
    }
    return newPolymer;
}

public static Boolean repeatedEveryTime(String text, char letter, int numberTime) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (letter == text.charAt(i)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == numberTime) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```